# Every 2nd repeater loop

Tags: c#, loops, repeater

I wish to store two different divs in my repeater item template depending on the current loop.
Basicly i want every 2nd loop to output a div container stored to the right, and the others to be stored in the left.

How could i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use alternate template:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <div class="left">
         Left one
     </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <AlternatingItemTemplate>
     <div class="right">
        Right one
     </div>
  </AlternatingItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the `AlternatingItemTemplate` approach, which might be uneasy to handle when mixed with code behind code, if the matter is just to set a class or style on your div, you can use the following :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
      <div class='<%#Container.ItemIndex % 2 ==0?"classLeft":"classRight"%>'>                            
     </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```